# Looping through folders with a specific year choosen by the user

Tags: vba, excel

I have several folders with names like "*2016 - *2017- *2018" and I would like to give the user the possibility to choose the year (as string) with an input box and depending on that browse the folders that have the year choosen by the user but it's not getting in the loop. In description an example of how the folders are arranged and an MCVE

```
Option Explicit

'folder t2-2018
'folder t2-2017
'folder t1-2016
'
'
'
'
Public Sub picking()
Dim Fso As Object
Dim subf As Variant
Dim f1 As Object, f2 As Object
Dim debut As Variant
Dim fin
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
debut = Application.InputBox("Veuillez saisir l'année de début", "Début", , , , , , 2)
fin = Application.InputBox("Veuillez saisir l'année de fin", "Fin", , , , , , 2)
subf = "C:\Users\A60179\Desktop\Nouveau dossier"
    For Each f1 In Fso.GetFolder(subf).subfolders
        If f1.Name Like debut Or f1.Name Like fin Then
        msgbox ("nom" & f1.Name)
            For Each f2 In f1.Files
                If f2.Name Like "*cahier*" Then
                msgbox ("ok")
                Else
                msgbox ("not ok")
                End If
            Next f2
        Else
        End If
    Next f1
End Sub
```

Comment: what's the issue with your current code?

Comment: It never goes in the loop,
`If f1.Name Like debut Or f1.Name Like fin Then` is not working

Comment: What are the values of f1.Name when you debug the application? Are you sure your `Like` is correct (I don't see any wildcards, so why using `Like`)?

Comment: I think the only scenario when it won't go into the loop is when there are no subfolders. I just tested it with a folder on my PC and it entered the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use:

```
Dim debut As Long, fin As Long
Dim folderYear As Long

Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
debut = Application.InputBox("Veuillez saisir l'année de début", "Début", , , , , , 2)
fin = Application.InputBox("Veuillez saisir l'année de fin", "Fin", , , , , , 2)
subf = "C:\Users\A60179\Desktop\Nouveau dossier"

For Each f1 In Fso.GetFolder(subf).SubFolders
    folderYear = CLng(Split(f1.Name, "-")(1)) ' get the last "part" of folder name
    If folderYear >= debut And folderYear <= fin Then
```

Should the folder name pattern be “year - folder” then just adopt:

```
folderYear = CLng(Split(f1.Name, "-")(0))
```

Comment: if the folder were 2018-folder how would i procede to get the first part as opposite to `CLng(Split(f1.Name, "-")(1))` where it gets the last part

Comment: See edited answer. If it solves your question please consider marking it as accepted. Thank you